# using "who" when referring to things: is it okay?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I was doing some problems sets and came across the sentence, "I used to work for a company who manufactured automatic processing machines." I need to find errors in this sentence and I think one of them is to change "machines" to "machine."

Also, I thought maybe "who" shouldn't be used because it's the company it's referring to, but am I right? This is not the first time I came across sentences that use "who" for other than human beings.

So, is using "who" to refer to something other than human grammatically correct? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The more natural thing for this sentence would be to use "that", and it is almost certainly the error you are being asked to fix:

> "I used to work for a company **that** manufactured automatic processing machines."

You can use "who" to refer to animals, especially when talking to them.  *"Who's a good dog?"* (wag, wag, bark!) *"That's right, you are!"*

But companies are "it" and "that"...or possibly "they".

> "Have you seen the latest video game from Bungie?  They really are rehashing Halo, I don't see much new in it."

Changing "machines" to "machine" would not be correct at all.  Although if the company really only made one thing, you might say:

> "I used to work for a company that manufactured **an** automatic processing machine."

This would most likely suggest that the company only made instances of one model of this machine *(as opposed to the idea that they'd only made one machine, ever)*.  They might--as @Jim points out--manufacture other things.

Note that you can use other ways to refer to "companies".  For instance:

> From the people who brought you "Finding Nemo" and "Toy Story" comes an all-new animated adventure...

You wouldn't--however--say:

> From the studio who brought you "Finding Nemo" and "Toy Story" comes an all-new animated adventure...

That's another case where you'd use *that* instead of *who*.

Comment: I don't think it means they only make that machine but simply that they only make one model.  Consider, *what companies out there make cell phones? Well, there's Samsung, Nokia... Apple makes one, well a couple actually, Amazon makes one too.*  This certainly does not imply that a phone is the only thing they make.

Comment: @Jim Fair enough.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Using "who" is strictly for pronouns like " he/she" however, for an object you're supposed to refer to it using  "whom".

Check this http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/who_whom.html for more information.

Comment: Why the down vote?..